# Change Content Template on Button Click Wpf

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm, ironpython

I have the following XAML:

```
<Window 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       Title="WpfApplication4" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="simpleErrorTemplate">
            <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T1" />
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="detailedErrorTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T2" />
                <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T3" />
                <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T4" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
                        Value="{StaticResource simpleErrorTemplate}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button,Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource detailedErrorTemplate}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
        <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Button" Height="40" Width="129" Margin="88,5,76,5" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I had like to change the GUI style the moment I click the button just like it happends when DataTrigger is set for the Checkbox.

The code Behind looks as follows however the moment I click the button the window closes and no result.

```
import wpf
from System.Windows import Application, Window

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication4.xaml')

    def Button_Click1(self, sender, e):
        self.ContentTemplate = Window.Resources.FindName(self,'detailedErrorTemplate') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

Why the template wont change?

Thank you.

Comment: A ContolTemplate isn’t a DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with ironpython, but in your click handler it looks like you're setting the ContentTemplate of your window, which seems incorrect. I assume your detailedErrorTemplate is supposed to apply to  your ContentControl. In this case you need to add x:Name to your ContentControl (i.e.: x:Name="TheContentControl") in order to reference the ContentControl in your code behind and set (in c#)

```
TheContentControl.Template = this.Resources["detailedErrorTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
```

You have key's for your resources, not Names, so you need to index the resource dictionary by the key.

*Edit* details based on comments.

1. In your xaml, change your line

   ```
   <ContentControl>
   ```

to

```
 <ContentControl x:Name="TheContentControl">
```

2. Since we now have a name for the ContentControl, you can properly change the ControlTemplate of the ContentControl (NOT the window. I understand that your ContentControl effectively encompasses the Window, but you can't just assign that ControlTemplate meant for the ContentControl to the Window like that). Change your line of code from:

   ```
   self.ContentTemplate = Window.Resources.FindName(self,'detailedErrorTemplate')
   ```

to (I hope I'm doing the syntax correctly).

```
 self.TheContentControl.Template = self.Resources['detailedErrorTemplate']
```

Comment: Sorry mate but I cant understand really how to implement what you suggested

Comment: which part? :) the name? the click handler?

Comment: I would like to change the template of the whole window, basically what im trying to do for 2 days and cant find is to load a whole new XAML with different buttons and whatever. But since I cant find how to do it, im trying to change the template of the whole window and not of  specific control.

Comment: Wait, you said "I had like to change the GUI style the moment I click the button just like it happends when DataTrigger is set for the Checkbox." Your DataTrigger does NOT change the template for the whole window - it changes the template only for the contentcontrol.

Comment: In the example above the contentcontrol is basically the whole gui window from what I understand since its just changing from 1 textbox to 3, unless I understand something incorrect.

Comment: There's definitely some misunderstanding here. It pays to specifically refer to and target specific controls you're actually trying to change. My answer was originally correct based on your response. I've added details to hopefully help you understand. As Ed said in his comment, a Window's ContentTemplate property is a DataTemplate, not a ControlTemplate. You should do a little more reading on MSDN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162214/discussion-between-ben-and-rowbear).